# How do I modularize the data I'm getting from an API into an independent function

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JS and I'm having problems trying fetching data from an API and modularizing it. I have no problem getting the async/await function to work into the main js file, but if I separate it in an independent js file and I call it with import from the main js, the data simply doesn't show at all (it's some charts I'm trying to render). I know I'm doing somethng wrong and I'd really appreciate any help with this

this is the code I'm working with, it's two separate js files

```
export const fetchApi = async (url) => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = response.json();
    return data;


________________________________________________________

import { fetchApi } from "./fetch_2";

async function getData() {

    const response = await fetchApi('https://api.gael.cloud/general/public/clima');
    const weather = await response.json();

    const regions = [];
    const temperatures = [];


    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        regions.push(weather[i].Estacion);
        temperatures.push(weather[i].Temp);
    }

   //chart I'm trying to render using the fetched data

    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: regions,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "regiones",
                        backgroundColor: color =>{
                            console.log(color)
                            let colors = color.raw >= 15 ? 'orange' : 'lightblue'
                            return colors
                        },
                        data: temperatures
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                   legend: {
                      display: false,
                      color: 'white'
                   },
                   
                }
            },
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need a `let` declaration for `i`. Also you should be awaiting `response.json()` in one place or another, not both.

Comment: const weather = response ?

Comment: I deleted the awaited response in the main js file, I also added the let declaration in the for iteration, nothing happened